# Android Studio: Waiting for type "handshake" error for native modules

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I recently updated to Android Studio 3.6 and I get the following error while building my app which has C/C++ native modules:

```
/CMakeLists.txt : C/C++ release|armeabi-v7a : Waiting for type "handshake".
Affected Modules: MyC++Module
```

I have a gcc dependency and hence I am using a specific version of NDK which supports gcc.

From build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION)
    buildToolsVersion project.ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION
    ndkVersion project.ANDROID_BUILD_NDK_VERSION
```

From project settings:

```
ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION=17
ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=28
ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION=28
ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=28.0.3
ANDROID_BUILD_NDK_VERSION=17.2.4988734
```

This error is seen when I build from terminal:

```
 C/C++ debug|armeabi-v7a : Failed to activate protocol version: Generator "Android Gradle - Ninja" not supported.

externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++11"
                arguments "-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static",
                          "-DANDROID_CPP_FEATURES=rtti exceptions",
                          "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=gcc",
                          "-GAndroid Gradle - Ninja"

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags "-std=c++11"
            arguments "-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static",
                      "-DANDROID_CPP_FEATURES=rtti exceptions",
                      "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=gcc",
                      "-GNinja"

        }
    }
```

"-GAndroid Gradle - Ninja" is not supported anymore?

Comment: Check `cmake --help` to see what generators are available. Be sure you use the same cmake as gradle does.